# Some Alt keys changes my RichTextBox font

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, fonts, richtextbox

I am creating some Hindi typing application in Windows Forms.

I have used `KrutiDev010` Font, there are some alt key control codes for some characters but if I enter some other alt key control codes, like `Alt+0261`, `Alt+025896` then it prints a charters `ą`, `攨` respectively and changes my textbox font to "Arial".

How to block only those alt key control codes which change my RichTextBox fonts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the default behavior.
The `RichTextBox` Control automatically finds a fallback font to represent characters that the current Font can't handle.
If not otherwise instructed, it changes the Font selection with the fallback Font.

Read this rant about the same default behavior of the `RichTextBox` ancestor (the `RichEdit` / `MsftEdit` Control, from which the `WinForms` control derives): [Don't change the font, dammit!](http://archives.miloush.net/michkap/archive/2006/02/13/531110.html)

There are means to change this behavior. At least in the way the `RichTextBox` Control reports the current Font and Font selection. The `C++` code in the previous blog post is one.

A StackOverflow Question/Answer on the subject:
[How to force a Win32 RichEdit fallback to SimSun with East Asian text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34784110/how-to-force-a-win32-richedit-fallback-to-simsun-with-east-asian-text).

But you don't need to *fallback* to `C++` for this.
See the [RichTextBox.LanguageOption](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.richtextbox.languageoption) and the [RichTextBoxLanguageOptions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.richtextboxlanguageoptions) flags.

You can insert this line of code right after the `InitializeComponent()` proc in your Form Constructor:

```
richTextBox1.LanguageOption = RichTextBoxLanguageOptions.DualFont;
```

or

```
richTextBox1.LanguageOption = RichTextBoxLanguageOptions.DualFont | 
                              RichTextBoxLanguageOptions.UIFonts;
```

There's a slight difference. See the reference Docs and test this behavior in your specific context.
If you insert an Unicode symbol that the current Font cannot handled, a fallback is always possible, but the `RichTextBox` UI will not change the Font, not even the `SelectionFont`.
And [Clipboard.SetText()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.clipboard.settext), [Clipboard.GetText()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.clipboard.gettext) will work as usual.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `KeyDown` event to supress/block the Alt key from functioning ...

```
    private void txt_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Alt)
        {
            e.SuppressKeyPress = true;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Block only those alt keys which change my textbox fonts.

Comment: Do you have a complete list of those Alt control codes that change the font? If not, then your only option will be to reset the font after each key press, which will probably be a performance nightmare!

Comment: I've updated your question, as it seemed like you were asking how to block the Alt key, rather than specific control codes :0)