# LinkLabel width not enough in particular cases

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, controls

env: VS2019 16.6.3 on Windows Server 2008 R2 x64

Reproduce steps:

1. create a normal .net4.0 winform project
2. drag a `CheckBox` on `Form1`
3. add a new form (auto name to `Form2`)
4. drag two `LinkLabel`s and a `Label` on `Form2`, make sure the z-order is: `linkLabel1`, `linkLabel2`, `label1`
5. set `linkLabel1` and `linkLabel2` font to `Arial, 10.5pt`
6. register the `Load` event for `Form2`, write codes:

   ```cs
   linkLabel2.Text = string.Empty;
   linkLabel1.Text = "<未选择>";
   linkLabel2.Text = "<未选择>";
   ```
7. modify `Main` method contents to follow codes in `program.cs`:

   ```cs
   Application.EnableVisualStyles();
   Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);

   new Form1().ShowDialog();
   Application.Run(new Form2());
   ```
8. `F5`, close `Form1`, now you can see the `linkLabel1` width is not enough

[demo.zip](https://1drv.ms/u/s!AqgXZLXb9C8KbTL4fQ_mhIZ65fc?e=LU1qiY)

[image]

I do reported to [Developer Community](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/1159811/linklabel-width-not-enough-in-particular-cases.html), but based on my past experience, they prefer `close`, so i decided post here too.

Comment: *They* don't prefer to close, *They* prefer to fix what can be fixed, possibly without disrupting existing applications. These fixes often come with Framework updates. Try FW 4.8. Btw, 10.5 is an *odd* Font size.

Comment: this issue not only about font size, every step is important.

Comment: It looks fine on `Windows 8.1`, not cutoff. In your screenshot, the `label1` font looks like `Courier New`, which may indicate the OS fonts are limited. As long as `AutoSize = true` is set, then it should work as expected, unless the `OS` is reporting the wrong size. Maybe there is an update or service pack that fixed this issue.

Comment: my OS lang is chinese, `label1` font and size are default, no problem.@Loathing

Comment: this issue is not about display, it's about width value, `linkLabel1.Width` is `49`, `linkLabel2.Width` is `65`, I running it on Win10, same issue.@Loathing

Comment: @ahdung You may have noticed (or not), that Arial doesn't provide any Japanese symbol. So, how does the Control show Japanese kanji if the Font doesn't have any? Read a bout Font Fallback here, for example: [How can a Label control display Japanese characters properly when the Font used doesn't support this language?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51612395/7444103). .Net Framework (and the System) has had a number of updates, some quite recent, to support Asian symbols, specifically tied to the size of these symbol. When dealing with Font Fallback and Asian languages, some extra care is needed.

Comment: @Jimi I think not the reason, `linkLabel2` no problem.