# Get the font type of a given text

Tags: c#, winforms, fonts, styles

I write an application that handles text.
I must be able to determine the FontFamily and the FontStyle of each word that is contained in a RichTextBox.Text, as the different font types must be handled differently.
I found ways to SET the font type, but I was unable to find an example in which the font type is examined and the FontFamily and the FontStyle are determined.
Thank you in advance.

Comment: Font type of **what** text? Inside of a label, button, `RichTextBox` etc?

Comment: If you can __select__ a word the font will be accessible in [`rtb.SelectionFont`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.richtextbox.selectionfont?view=netframework-4.7.2) etc.. If you have trouble, show the code that gives the trouble..

Comment: An addendum to what @TaW said. You might have to deal with the Font Fallback feature of text-related controls. The Font won't match any of the user-defined Fonts. It this could be the case, read [this about Font fallback](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51608365/how-can-label-control-display-japanese-characters-properly-when-font-of-the-labe?answertab=active#tab-top) and related adjustments you may won't to perform: [Some Alt keys changes my RichTextBox font](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51441064/some-alt-keys-changes-my-richtextbox-font?answertab=active#tab-top)